# nginx config issues with php container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, containers, typo3

I am facing an issue and I appreciate any help can be provided.

So I have two containers one nginx and the other typo3 which is php basically. I think I have an issue with nginx configs and seems very strange. I noticed when nginx container doesn't have the files which php container has, it return 404. So if these files are existing also in nginx, I get the expected response even if these files are dummy (has no real code).

So when the files are existing on nginx, I see from the logs of php container that nginx is requesting these files which prove that nginx is not serving these files from its own.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # TYPO3 Backend URLs
    location = /typo3 {
        rewrite ^ /typo3/;
    }

    location /typo3/ {
        absolute_redirect off;
        try_files $uri /typo3/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Tried these tests:

- nginx has no site data and php has site data -> 404
- nginx and php have both the same files -> works
- ngins has dummy files and the names are the same as the files of php -> works, nginx requests the files of php container and doesn't serve his own dummy data.

Comment: Hello! Take a look at [Digital Ocean NGINXConfig](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx) tool. I think you are really going to like this.